# jquery inject image repeating issue

Tags: jquery

I have a bunch of divs (with class `nectar-post-grid-item`) and i am using jquery to inject an image into them. This works fine. I also have an AJAX load more button which pulls in and displays more divs onto the page - I want to add the injected image to these when they appear... I have this all working... BUT... the image is added a 2nd time to the initial set of divs that are in view on the page load... Is there a way I can stop this duplication when the AJAX call occurs?

```
$(".nectar-post-grid-item").prepend("<img src='/wp-content/themes/salient-child/images/aspectTrans.png' class='PostGridItemTrans' alt='' />");
  }
```

The above is the code to inject the image which i call on `window.load` and also on `document.ajaxComplete`

So on initial page load the divs "nectar-post-grid-item" all have an image with class "PostGridItemTrans" added. This is fine, on click on the AJAX load button the next bunch of divs all get this "PostGridItemTrans" image added - but the original divs get it added another time, this continues with each AJAX load call...

I Was hoping to try and look at the contents of the "nectar-post-grid-item" div to see if an element with the class "PostGridItemTrans" exists- and if not add it...

```
$(".nectar-post-grid-item").each(function() {
  
  if($(this).children('img.PostGridItemTrans').length == 0) {
  
  $(".nectar-post-grid-item").prepend("<img src='/wp-content/themes/salient-child/images/aspectTrans.png' class='PostGridItemTrans' alt='' />");
  
  }
  
  });
```

HTML

```
<div class="nectar-post-grid-item">
</div>
<div class="nectar-post-grid-item">
</div>
<div class="nectar-post-grid-item">
</div>
```

Will then become

```
<div class="nectar-post-grid-item">
<img src='/wp-content/themes/salient-child/images/aspectTrans.png' class='PostGridItemTrans' alt='' />
</div>
<div class="nectar-post-grid-item">
<img src='/wp-content/themes/salient-child/images/aspectTrans.png' class='PostGridItemTrans' alt='' />
</div>
<div class="nectar-post-grid-item">
<img src='/wp-content/themes/salient-child/images/aspectTrans.png' class='PostGridItemTrans' alt='' />
</div>
```

But after a click on the AJAX load more button which brings in more emtpy `<div class=""></div>`s I get

```
<div class="nectar-post-grid-item">
<img src='/wp-content/themes/salient-child/images/aspectTrans.png' class='PostGridItemTrans' alt='' />
<img src='/wp-content/themes/salient-child/images/aspectTrans.png' class='PostGridItemTrans' alt='' />
</div>
<div class="nectar-post-grid-item">
<img src='/wp-content/themes/salient-child/images/aspectTrans.png' class='PostGridItemTrans' alt='' />
<img src='/wp-content/themes/salient-child/images/aspectTrans.png' class='PostGridItemTrans' alt='' />
</div>
<div class="nectar-post-grid-item">
<img src='/wp-content/themes/salient-child/images/aspectTrans.png' class='PostGridItemTrans' alt='' />
<img src='/wp-content/themes/salient-child/images/aspectTrans.png' class='PostGridItemTrans' alt='' />
</div>
```

Comment: You haven't shown the code which adds the `div`s.  Can you add a simplified version of that?

Comment: I believe document.ajaxComplete will call every time any ajax call completes on the page and this is probably what is re-adding the same images when the later ajax calls are completed, not sure why you would want this if you loading the images on document load this should be redundant?

Answer (score 0):

The approach you were trying should be fine, you just need to target the *current* matching elements when prepending, not all of them.  Working snippet - each div only gets 1 image:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Run for any divs on the page at load time, this is the same
    // as your current window.load handler
    prependImages();

    // And run again after some new ones are added, this is the same
    // as your existsing ajaxComplete handler
    $button.on('click', function() {
        $container.prepend(newHTML);
        prependImages();
    });
});

let image = 'https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/Img/favicon.ico?v=ec617d715196';
let newHTML = '<div class="nectar-post-grid-item"></div><div class="nectar-post-grid-item"></div><div class="nectar-post-grid-item"></div>';
let $button = $('button');
let $container = $('.container');

function prependImages() {
    $(".nectar-post-grid-item").each(function() {
        if ($(this).find('img.PostGridItemTrans').length === 0) {
            $(this).prepend("<img src='" + image + "' class='PostGridItemTrans' alt='' />");
        }
    });
}
```

```css
.nectar-post-grid-item {
    border: black 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
    <div class="nectar-post-grid-item"></div>
    <div class="nectar-post-grid-item"></div>
    <div class="nectar-post-grid-item"></div>
</div>

<button>Add More</button>
```

Here's another approach I wrote out before looking at the above idea.  You haven't shown us the code which adds the `div`s, which is probably where it is easiest to address this issue.   I'll use some pseudo-code - let's assume you get a JSON response from your back end, and in your `success` callback you are generating and inserting the new HTML.  Something like:

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    url: "somewhere.com/your/backend/uri",
    success: function (json) {
        // Maybe something like this
        let html;
        $.each(json, function(i, item) {
            html += '<div class="nectar-post-grid-item">' + 
                ... item ... something ... 
                '</div>';
        });

        // So now you have a new chunk of HTML to add to the DOM
        $("#something").prepend(html);
    }
});
```

Since you are adding `div`s which mach the selector in your `ajaxComplete()`, they will get the new images, but so do any previous `div`s matching that selector.  Every time you click your button the image will be repeated in the `div`s that already have the image(s).

So you need to distinguise between the new `div`s and any existing ones.  You can't use the parent selector (`#something` in my pseudo-code above) since the next set will also be added in there.  So how about including a class to identify them.  Update your AJAX `success` handler to do something like this:

```
$.each(json, function(i, item) {
    // Add a dummy class we can use to identify new items
    html += '<div class="new nectar-post-grid-item">' + 
        ... item ... something ... 
        '</div>';
});
```

Now in your `ajaxComplete()` you can target just the `new` elements, and once handled, remove the `new` class so they won't match next time around:

```
$(".new.nectar-post-grid-item")
    .prepend("<img src='your-image' class='PostGridItemTrans'/>")
    .removeClass('new');
```